# Installing .net 3.5 on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to silently install .net 3.5 on Windows 2008 R2 using the dotNetFx35setup.exe (2.5) meg file and silent mode, or do you alway have to install from Server manager?

Thanks

Comment: Should be moved to ServerFault?

Comment: You can install it using PowerShell: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2010/01/08/how-to-install-net-framework-3-5-sp1-on-windows-server-2008-r2-environments.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 2008 R2 version onwards .NET 3.5.1 is part of windows component which can only be installed via Add/Remove features in server manager. It will not let you install through this installer.